# Force Visual Studio to insert relative file reference paths

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, typescript

I'm currently writing a TypeScript application, and I'm trying to add references to other files in my solution by dragging and dropping a file from the solution explorer into the typescript file that I'm working on.

Up until last week, visual studio was inserting the following code at the top of my file:

```
/// <reference path="lib/lib.d.ts" />
```

However now it's inserting a path similar to the following:

```
/// <reference path="file:///C:/TFS/Branch/scripts/lib/lib.d.ts" />
```

I need relative paths for my work because the project has to work on multiple machines, is there any way to force visual studio to create relative paths instead of absolute paths?

Thanks in advance!

Griffork.

Comment: Have you installed an update that could have caused this? I'm using Visual Studio 2012, TypeScript 0.8.2.0 and Web Essentials 2.4.5 - and it still behaves correctly, i.e. inserting the relative path. Also, are you editing files within a project or just on their own?

Comment: Relative paths will still work, so why not just add the path manually? FWIW I have the same setup as @SteveFenton except Web Essentials 2.5.1 and get relative paths as long as I am working inside a project.

Comment: It's more a matter of inconvenience than necessity, I will try re-installing the plugins later when I've finished my current task.
The files are on a project from a TFS server.
I'm using: 
Visual Studio 2012
Typescript 0.8.2.0
Web Essentials 2.4
Visual Studio Extensions Library for JavaScript 1.0.8514.0
Productivity Power Tools 11.0.51106.2
and Microsoft Web Developer Tools 1.0.30710.0
I have NestIn as well, however it is disabled as it does not appear to be working with my version of VS.

Comment: Oh, and JScript vsdoc Stub Generator 2012 1.3.0.
Sorry for the wall of text, apparently newlines aren't preserved in comments <.<'

Comment: So I uninstalled and re-installed Typescript and Web Essentials (because of a different problem) and VS is still inserting absolute paths. I should have checked with both of them uninstalled but it didn't cross my mind at the time.

Comment: It works fine for me right now with 0.8.3 and webessentials 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to a Typescript Project and it started working. I think the problem was in the way I had set up my Web Project.

Comment: Still, if anyone can figure out exactly what caused it, I will accept their answer.